# facing Error while reading text file in c++

Tags: c++, file

i am facing this error while reading the text file and the file contain a "name" string.
[image: i am facing this error while reading the text file.]

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    ifstream read;
    read.open("sam.txt");
    while (read.eof())
    {
        read.get(ch);
        cout << ch << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you see why your while loop will never run?

Comment: yes i got it ... but now i am facing anoter problem.
the file contain the string "name"
and the output of is
n
a
m
e
e
why it is printing e two times.

Comment: Can you post as text (edit your post)?  (Like highlighting the text, then pressing Ctrl-C)  Your image is difficult to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you mention in the comments happens because when the end of the file is reached, get fails and does not overwrite the previous value of ch. A quick way to fix that is:

```
while (!read.eof())
{
    if(read.get(ch))
    {
        cout << ch << endl;
    }
}
```

Now ch is printed only when `read.get(ch)` returns successfully.

Comment: but i did not get if(read,get(ch)) statment..... can you please explain this

Comment: @SamiMalik get() returns the character read, or the EOF value if no characters are available in the stream. That means that whenever it returns a character, the if statement is evaluated as true and executes the following block. When EOF is reached, it is equivalent to it being 0, so the if statement evaluates it as false and does not execute.